# Php MYSql, Different kind of cross tab Report

Tags: php, mysql, report, crosstab

I got 2 tables, comparitive_st_sup and comparitive_statement1

comparitive_st_sup fields are as follows:

- tender_id
- supplier_name
- item_name
- quantity
- unitprice
- total

comparitive_statement1 fields are as follows:

- tender_id
- sup_name (supplier name)
- coc_charges
- export_charges
- iata_charges

Both the tables are linked by supplier_name. comparitive_st_sup table has many item_name (items or Products) for a single supplier. Where as comparitive_statement1 have details of supplier and its cost (quantity, unitprice and total)

Now i need a report to come in the following format:

```html
<p>Data from comparitive_st_sup table</p>
<table border="1" width="100%">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3" width="33%">
  <p align="center"><b>Supplier 1 Name</b></td>
  <td colspan="3" width="33%">
  <p align="center"><b>Supplier 2 Name</b></td>
  <td colspan="3" width="33%">
  <p align="center"><b>Supplier 3 Name</b></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Item name</td>
  <td>unit price</td>
  <td>qty</td>
  <td>item name</td>
  <td>unit price</td>
  <td>qty</td>
  <td>item name</td>
  <td>unit price</td>
  <td>qty</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>item name</td>
  <td>unit price</td>
  <td>qty</td>
  <td>item name</td>
  <td>unit price</td>
  <td>qty</td>
  <td>item name</td>
  <td>unit price</td>
  <td>qty</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3">Data from comparitive_statement1 table</td>
  <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3">
  <p align="center"><b>Supplier 1 Name</b></td>
  <td colspan="3">
  <p align="center"><b>Supplier 2 Name</b></td>
  <td colspan="3">
  <p align="center"><b>Supplier 3 Name</b></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3">COC Charges</td>
  <td colspan="3">COC Charges</td>
  <td colspan="3">COC Charges</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3">Export Charges</td>
  <td colspan="3">Export Charges</td>
  <td colspan="3">Export Charges</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3">Iata_Charges</td>
  <td colspan="3">Iata_Charges</td>
  <td colspan="3">Iata_Charges</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

How can i achieve this? Pls Help. Thanx in advance.